# Adding environment variables into Github Actions for Cypress tests

Tags: yaml, continuous-integration, environment-variables, cypress, github-actions

I am trying to add some environment variables into my cypress action inside of the GitHub Actions.

My Yaml file looks as the following.

```
name: Run cypress tests

on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        env:
          CYPRESS_TEST_VARIABLE: 200
          CYPRESS_ANOTHER_TEST_VARIABLE: prsnlmgr-713a4
          CYPRESS_PROJECT_ID: prsnlmgr
        with:
          start: npm start
          wait-on: "http://localhost:3000" # Waits for above
          record: false
          parallel: false # Runs test in parallel using settings above
```

Cypress docs specifically state that you should prefix your env variables with CYPRESS_, which is what I am doing. I ran into an issue where for some reason my env variable comes out as undefined. I am wondering what am I doing wrong.

I tried setting variables on many levels including on the global YAML file level (which I assume sets them in each job that is run) and inside of the specific Cypress action. The problem is that CYPRESS_TEST_VARIABLE and CYPRESS_ANOTHER_TEST_VARIABLE are passed down. I do not use them inside of my cypress project. However, I do use the variable PROJECT_ID, and this one for some reason comes out as undefined. Locally I set these variables inside of the cypress.env.json file that looks like the following

```
  "TEST_UID": "{{value}}",
  "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID": "{{value}}",
  "GCLOUD_PROJECT": "./serviceAccount.json",
  "TEST_ACCOUNT_EMAIL": "{{value}}",
  "TEST_ACCOUNT_PASSWORD": "{{value}}",
  "FIREBASE_API_KEY": "{{value}}",
  "PROJECT_ID": "{{value}}",
  "FIREBASE_APP_ID": "{{value}}"
}
```

For obvious reasons I am not checking it into the GitHub repo.

So I made a conclusion that somehow the naming conflicts and my PROJECT_ID and any other variable that is inside of the cypress.env.json passes down as undefined.

I know this might sounds a little confusing, but wondering if anyone else have encountered this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Per [**Env** - Specify the env argument with env parameter](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action#env) - the `env` attribute belongs beneath `with` and not its parent `uses`.

```yaml
      - name: Cypress run
        uses: cypress-io/github-action@v5
        with:
          env:
            CYPRESS_TEST_VARIABLE: 200
            CYPRESS_ANOTHER_TEST_VARIABLE: prsnlmgr-713a4
            CYPRESS_PROJECT_ID: prsnlmgr
          start: npm start
          wait-on: "http://localhost:3000" # Waits for above
          record: false
          parallel: false # Runs test in parallel using settings above
```

Check the linked documentation, it also gives another example for the `CYPRESS_` prefix (yours looks good).